# I've trained dataset using XGB Classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost, ray-train

I got this part of the code from my teammate for our project, I got this error in local I have trained dataset using XGB Classifier.

my code is:

```
#  XGBoost Classifier Model
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# instantiate the model
xgb = XGBClassifier()

# fit the model 
xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

then I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 8
      5 xgb = XGBClassifier()
      7 # fit the model 
----> 8 xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/core.py:730, in require_keyword_args.<locals>.throw_if.<locals>.inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
    728 for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args):
    729     kwargs[k] = arg
--> 730 return func(**kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py:1471, in XGBClassifier.fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, base_margin_eval_set, feature_weights, callbacks)
   1466     expected_classes = self.classes_
   1467 if (
   1468     classes.shape != expected_classes.shape
   1469     or not (classes == expected_classes).all()
   1470 ):
-> 1471     raise ValueError(
   1472         f"Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.  "
   1473         f"Expected: {expected_classes}, got {classes}"
   1474     )
   1476 params = self.get_xgb_params()
   1478 if callable(self.objective):

ValueError: Invalid classes inferred from unique values of `y`.
```

Expected: [0 1], got [-1 1] ,, I heard the y_train must be encoded in a newer update but I'm kinda new to these things I have no clue how to do that either.

Answer (score 1):

This means you need to **encode your labels** in a fresher update. Ideally right before training, you encode.

```
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

[Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)